# A comparison between "expand", "propagate" and "promote"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-difference

Imagine a country's president giving a speech against making other culture's rules widespread and emphasizing that we have to stick with our own ancient traditions. He is highlighting his opinion that some bad policies and decisions in country's macro-management has lead the youths to face a big cultural downfall.

I was wondering if you could help me to find the best choice from among my listed choices below:

> By doing these actions they are ............ an alien culture among our youths.
>
> a) [promoting](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/promote)
>
> b) [propagating](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/propagate)
>
> c) [expanding](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/expand)

Based on dictionary definitions, they all work, but for me the best choice is 'b'. What do you think on it?

Comment: Since he is speaking but not implementing anything yet, I would use *promoting*. *propagating* indicates some action has occurred, and *expanding* indicates an action based on a previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct and B) **propagate** seems to fit best, in terms of your linked definition:

> "to spread opinions, lies, or beliefs among a lot of people"

*Promote* can also work in the right context.

> Their philosophy is to promote peace and harmony among all peoples of the world, but many governments consider this to be a "corrupting" influence on the country's youth.

However the overall sentence still feels like an imperfect translation from another language and not natural English.

Some alternatives:

> Their actions propagate an alien culture among our youth.
>
> They are trying to propagate an alien culture among our youth.

Comment: You should explain why you chose B).